# find a selection of elements adjacent sum = 10

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Description:
Given matrix [x] [y], with x- rows and y- number of columns . Filled random numbers from 0 to 5 inclusive .

Description of finding a solution : the solution is considered to be a set of matrix elements that are adjacent to each other ( diagonal neighborhood is not taken into account ) and the sum of the number are 10. Each element of the matrix can be used 1 time for a decision . The solution may have any number of digits. The decision must end any number other than zero .

Example:
given

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 0
2 3 4 5 1 2
```

Solution 1 : (1 - 2 - 3 - 4)

```
0 **1** 2 3 4 5
1 **2** 3 4 5 0
2 **3** **4** 5 1 2
```

i tried to do smth like this, but it is wrong, i dont know when i must stop,
 Solution it is a class which contains mair of indexes, pls help me.

```
void xxx(int colCount, int rowCount, int currentRow, int currentCol, int** matrix, int sum, Solution *solution, int solCount) {

        sum += matrix[currentRow][currentCol];
        matrix[currentRow][currentCol] = -1;
        if(sum > 10){
            sum -  = matrix[currentRow][currentCol];
            return;
        } else if(sum == 10){
            solution[solCount].additem(currentRow, currentCol);            
            return xxx(5,5,currentRow - 1, currentCol, matrix, sum, solution, solCount+1);
        } else {
            //UP
            if( currentRow > 0 && matrix [currentRow - 1][currentCol] != -1){            
                xxx(5,5,currentRow - 1, currentCol, matrix, sum, solution,solCount);
            }
            //LEFT
            if(currentCol > 0 && matrix [currentRow][currentCol-1] != -1){
                xxx(5,5,currentRow, currentCol - 1, matrix, sum, solution,solCount);
            }
            //DOWN
            if(currentRow + 1 < colCount && matrix[currentRow + 1][currentCol] != -1){
                xxx(5,5,currentRow + 1, currentCol, matrix, sum, solution,solCount);
            }
            //RIGHT
            if(currentCol + 1 < rowCount && matrix[currentRow][currentCol + 1] != -1){
                xxx(5,5,currentRow, currentCol + 1, matrix, sum, solution,solCount);
            }
        }     
}
```

Comment: the solution is regular BFS or DFS with acceptable solution having path with sum of 10

Comment: well said. though, in short: @Assares try to outline/sketch the algorithm that you want to use first and then try to program it. test30 gave you a useful hint, though there might be other ways of solving it.